# shmat() returning different address for different programs, all having same shared memory

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

In shared memory, as i understand, the same logical address is shared between two process attached to it using `shmat()` call. Then why i am getting different memory address (in the output) for the programs below, even though they share same address.

> **//Shm_Server.C**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXSIZE 27

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    char c;
    int shmid;
    key_t key = 5678;
    char *shm_addr, *s;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, MAXSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
        die("shmget");

    if ((shm_addr = (char *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
        die("shmat");
    printf("\nServer shm_addr = %x\n",shm_addr);

    s = shm_addr;
    for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        *s++ = c;

    while (*shm_addr != '*')
        sleep(1);

    if((shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0)) < 0)
        die("shmctl");
    exit(0);
}
```

> **//Shm_Client.C**

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXSIZE     27

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    int shmid;
    key_t key = 5678;
    char *shm_addr, *s;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, 0, 0666)) < 0)
        die("shmget");

    if ((shm_addr = (char *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
        die("shmat");
    printf("\nClient shm_addr = %x\n", shm_addr);

    //reading what the server put in shared memory
    for (s = shm_addr; *s != '\0'; s++)
        putchar(*s);
    putchar('\n');

    //Writing in shared memory
    *shm_addr = '*';
    exit(0);
}
```

> **Output:**

```
[xyz@xyz:Shm_ex] $ ./Shm_Server &
[1] 19489
[xyz@xyz:Shm_ex] $
Server shm_addr = d92b5000
./Shm_Client

Client shm_addr = eb3c4000
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
[xyz@xyz:Shm_ex] $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In shared memory, as i understand, the same logical address is shared
>   between two process attached to it using shmat() call.

In shared memory as I understand, the same **physical** address is shared between more than one processes attached to it. This physical address is mapped to all the virtual address spaces of the respective processes. So, `shmat()` will return different logical addresses.